# How do I get intellisense for linked Javascript files inside a HTML file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, cdn

I have a javascript file that I have stored in the same folder as a HTML file. I want to call functions in the javascript file from within a script tag in the HTML file. Somehow, I do not get intellisense for this even though the code works perfectly. Am I missing something? I noticed I do get intellisense for functions written in script blocks in the HTML file itself. But it does not seem to work for linked js files. I also saw the same behaviour when I link a javascript file from a CDN repository.
This is a standard feature in all IDEs, including Visual Studio. So how does it not work out of the box in VS Code?

Edit: Just adding a couple of images to highlight what I mean
[The javascript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HWns.png)
[The HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idLUC.png)

The first image shows the javascript file which contains a simple function while in the second image I am trying to call the same function (i.e. show_alert) but do not get any intellisense for the same.

Comment: and what if you had two HTML files that included the same javascript file but had different preceding scripts. how would/should intellisense work?

Comment: Can you put a codesandbox link here ?

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3465

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15377

This is a known issue, maybe update to newest version will help.

You can also check the settings>editor>JavaScript>intellisense>引用（Sorry, I don't know its proper translation  in English）

Turn it to web and add your file path to related items may help.

Comment: how is that even relevant? you seem to have misunderstood the question.